# Using minted in an appendix with tcolorbox, how can I specify code to be single-spaced while text is double-spaced?

Tags: tcolorbox, minted

I'm writing my appendix for my dissertation and I am inserting code but want the `minted` code inside the `tcolorbox` environment to be single spaced.

Here is my highlighted code `tex` file:

```latex
%%% ====================================================================
%%% Custom code highlighting using Minted and tikz
%%% ====================================================================

\usepackage{tikz}

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Specific colors used for code highlighting
%%% ====================================================================

\definecolor{matlabcodebg}{rgb}{0.99,0.99,1}
\definecolor{pythoncodebg}{rgb}{0.99,1,0.99}

%\usepackage{minted} % Already charged with tcblibrary minted

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,skins,breakable,hooks}

\usemintedstyle[python]{default} % Specific color scheme
\usemintedstyle[matlab]{default} % Specific color scheme

%%% ====================================================================
%%% Custom code highlighting using Minted
%%% ====================================================================

% Python footnotesize
\newtcbinputlisting{\pythoninput}[2][]{%
    listing file={#2},
    minted language=python,
    minted style=default,
    minted options={
        fontsize=\normal,
        linenos,
        numbersep=1mm,
        breaklines=true,
    },% <-- put other minted options inside the brackets
    overlay={%
        \begin{tcbclipinterior}
            \fill[gray!25] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=5mm]frame.north west);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}
    },
    colback=pythoncodebg,
    colframe=black!70,
    before skip=5pt plus 2pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced,% <-- put other tcolorbox options here
    listing only,#1
}
```

In my appendix, here is how I'm calling a script to be formatted:

```latex
%%% -*-LaTeX-*-
\documentclass[../Dissertation]{subfiles}

\doublespacing
\begin{document}
    
\chapter{The Third}

\section{Elastic Moduli}
\subsection{Python Elastic Moduli Curve Fitting}
    Python script used to fit a two-term standard linear solid model to creep
    data.
    \pythoninput{\subfix{Python/LmFit_Example_Lin2020.py}}

\section{Prony Series}
\subsection{Python Prony Series Curve Fitting}
    Python script used to fit an n'th-term Prony series model to creep data.
    \pythoninput{\subfix{Python/LmFit_Example.py}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like the code blocks to be single-spaced and I'm not sure the best way to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: This might work: in the initialization options given to `\newtcbinputlisting`, add `before=\singlespacing` and `after=\doublespacing`.

Comment: I gave that a shot and it didn't seem to change the output.  I did find this and it does seem to work!  ```code={\singlespacing}```.

Answer (score 1):

Inserted the following command inside the listing environment:

`code={\singlespacing}`